Join 2 pandas dataframes using best available combinations
Considering I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2 with 2 key columns, key1 and key2. I am looking for a way to join these 2 dataframes ignoring blanks and produce df3 as output.
input 1 (df1)
  key1 key2  val1
0    A    E     1
1    B    F     2
2    C    G     3
3    D    H     4

input 2 (df2)
  key1 key2  val2
0    A    E     5
1    B    F     6
2  NaN    G     7
3    D  NaN     8
4    A  NaN     9

expected output (df3)
  key1 key2  val1  val2
0    A    E     1     5
1    B    F     2     6
2  NaN    G     3     7
3    D  NaN     4     8

To explain further,

in row0 and row1, both key1 and key2 match between df1 and df2, so a join will work fine.
in row2, key1 does not match but key2 matches, so i still want to join just based on key2.
in row3, key1 matches but key2 does not match, so i still want to join just based on key1.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'key2':['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
    'val1':[1, 2, 3, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key1':['A', 'B', np.NaN, 'D', 'A'],
    'key2':['E', 'F', 'G', np.NaN, np.NaN],
    'val2':[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key1':['A', 'B', np.NaN, 'D'],
    'key2':['E', 'F', 'G', np.NaN],
    'val1':[1, 2, 3, 4],
    'val2':[5, 6, 7, 8]})


what if a row from a table matches multiple rows from other table?do you have such cases? or even worse , image (NaN,G) was (NaN, F) will it match with (B, F) ?

I have added a case where row0 in df1 matches with row0 and row4 in df2, in that case, i will go with row0 in df2 because its a better match than row4.

because both key1 and key2 values match between row0 in df1 and row0 in d2. if we compare row0 in df1 and row4 in df2, only key1 matches.

Is this the same question as here? If not how is it different? Have you tested my answer? If I understand correctly you've already asked this question 3 or 4 times, then deleted it. Please stick to one question and give feedback.

What have you tried? Help us help you: show us what you've tried that hasn't worked so we don't repeat it, and tell us what you already know how to do so that we don't need to explain everything in our answers.

this is not same as my previous question. in this question i want to join using available values and dont want to calculate any ranking. I tried using merge but it only returns rows where key1 and key2 are matching and not the best available match.

Well if you use my answer in the other question you'll get the expected output (example). You can just skip the part that assigns the rank, no?

the number of rows is very high and dont want to do cross joins / cartesian product.

There is no cross-join here.

If you don't want to use the approach that I proposed in your previous question, you could perform a merge for the two keys and the single keys separately, then concat and drop_duplicates to keep the first match:
tmp = df1.reset_index()

out = (pd.concat([df2.dropna(subset=['key1', 'key2'])
                     .merge(tmp, on=['key1', 'key2']),
                  df2.drop(columns='key1').dropna(subset='key2')
                     .merge(tmp.drop(columns='key1'), on='key2'),
                  df2.drop(columns='key2').dropna(subset='key1')
                     .merge(tmp.drop(columns='key2'), on='key1')])
         .drop_duplicates('index').drop(columns='index')
      )

Output:
  key1 key2  val2  val1
0    A    E     5     1
1    B    F     6     2
2  NaN    G     7     3
2    D  NaN     8     4


this will not work if i have a large number of key columns. the number of combinations will grow exponentially.

Well, there is no magic approach, if you want to merge considering the different possibilities you'll potentially have to test all combinations. Now you could improve the above code by checking the rows that remain after each intermediate and update the combinations, but in fine and in the worst case you might need to test all of them.
